# Authenticating Owncloud 8.0.3 users through a samba4 AD, how is it done?

Tags: samba4, owncloud

I have a samba4 domain with the samba4-server as domain controller and I also have a owncloud server.

I need to authenticate the owncloud users through the samba4 ldap server, but the configuration just says "incomplete" even if I know that all DNS configuration is correct.

```
ldap-server: ldap://172.16.64.230
user-dn: cn=Administrator,cn=Users,dc=test,dc=com
password: ••••••••
base-dn: dc=test,dc=com
```

Is there anyone that has solved authentication through samba4 AD with owncloud?

Answer (score 1):

I do owncloud authentication against samba4 without LDAP.

1. enable "external_user_support" app
2. check "/var/www/owncloud/apps/user_external/lib/smb.php" for "const SMBCLIENT = 'smbclient -L';" (add -L if missing)
3. edit "/var/www/owncloud/config/config.php" and append:

   'user_backends' =>
   array (
   0 =>
     array (
       'class' => 'OC_User_SMB',
       'arguments' =>
         array (
           0 => 'DC.DOMAIN.MYCOMANY.COM',
         ),
     ),
   )

Last versions of owncloud add the "-L" by default.

Don't forget to adapt "DC.DOMAIN.MYCOMANY.COM" to your samba4 hostname fqdn